# How to calculate value of one span value based on input value with jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

I have a span element and a textbox.

The Span values will be calculated instantly based on textbox values. The values are numbers and added a comma after every three digits.

My Code:

```js
$("#num2").keyup(function(e) {
    $("#num1").html(($("#num1").html()- $(this).val()));
    if (e.keyCode == 8 || e.keyCode == 46) {
         // will also change num1 when deleted or backspaced num2
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="num1">1,000</span> **1,000 is from table** 
<input type="text" name="num2" placeholder="Num2" class="form-control number" id="num2" autofocuum2s>
```

I expect the calculation will do properly.

Expect like:

1. If typed 20 in textbox , the span value will be: 980 (1,000-20=980) **is work but not sure**
2. If backspaced or deleted 0 in textbox :  the span will be → 998 (1,000-2=998) **my problem**

Answer (score 1):

Below is working snippet as per expectations.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
var spanValue=$("#num1").text();
$("#num2").keyup(function(e) {
        $("#num1").html((spanValue.replace(/,/g, '') - $(this).val().replace(/,/g, '')).toLocaleString('en'));
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="num1">1,000</span> **1,000 is selected from table** 
<input type="text" name="num2" placeholder="Num2" class="form-control number" id="num2" autofocuum2s>
```

Comment: there is no need to code in e.keyCode block ?

Comment: @KyawWintThu no

Comment: I have a problem that my span is from Ajax.

Comment: $.ajax({
            url: "fetch_data.php",
            method: "POST",
            success: function(data) {
                $("#type").html(data);
               
            }
        })

Comment: So, my span is not change value. How can i do?

Comment: I have changed html to text but it shows the element tags in page. like
<span id="num1">1,000</span> , not showing 1,000 only

Comment: it's return empty .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249801/discussion-between-kiran-joshi-and-kyaw-wint-thu).